# Build an array of table cell IDs for a column

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to know the most efficient way of using JS/jQuery to obtain the cell IDs and text for a single column of an HTML table (excluding the header), so that these two arrays can be passed into another function.

The function called is a widget that takes the ID and data and acts upon it.

I know the column headers, so presumably I can use this to select the correct column.

I see by searching, that there are many different ways of doing it, but which one would be most efficient?

Many Thanks
Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) jQuery extension

```
var data = $.map($('table td, table th'),function(ele,i) {
       return { id : $(ele).attr("id"), text:$(ele).text().trim()  }
});
```

data would contain all ids of cell and their corresponding text

Comment: Hey dude, Could you explain how I can put this into my Fiddle? - this looks interesting and because I am new to Jquery, I cannot seem to get it working :(

Comment: Ive so much to learn too...... One step further on this.. I looked at the function but its not clear....  If the table id is '12345' and the column header is 'ID xxxxx' How do I find the array of data and IDs with the above map function.. ive tried naively changing table td, table th, but Im getting something wrong...... (and thanks for the help.. much appreciated...)

Comment: what i did above is, i return array containing object which contain id and text, if you need separate arrays do something like http://jsfiddle.net/8yaoh3u5/4/ jquery api provide number of utility methods which we can use to such manipulations in easy way. they well explained in their documents.

Answer (score 0):

Efficient as in?

Something like this would be efficient in terms of the amount of code needed:

```
var tablecells = {};
$('table td, table th').each(function (i, cell) {
  tablecells[cell.id 
             || Math.floor(10000 + Math.random()*1000000).toString(16)] = 
                    {
                       isheader: /th$/i.test(cell.tagName),
                       text: cell.innerHTML
                    };
});
```

Or `tablecells` as array of objects:

```
var tablecells = [];
$('table td, table th').each(function (i, cell) {
  tablecells.push({ id: cell.id || Math.floor(10000 + Math.random()*1000000)
                                   .toString(16), 
                    isheader: /th$/i.test(cell.tagName),
                    text: cell.innerHTML  } );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually just finished doing this right now :)

I used the below Jquery which works fine for me.

```
var results = [];
var Ids = [];
$(document).ready(function () {


    $("#myTable tr:has(td)").not(':first').each(function () {
        var cell = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").html();
        results.push(cell)

    });

     $("#myTable td").not(':first').each(function () {
        var samecell = $(this).attr('id');
        Ids.push(samecell)

    });   

    alert(results);
    alert(Ids);
});
```

the `.not(':first')` will exclude your header `row` (at least in my HTML it does)

As for most efficient, I have no clue - I am new to Jquery. Not even sure I understood your question correctly :)

Goodluck friend!

I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8yaoh3u5/1/) so you can see it in action